# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) in Panda's For Loop

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, matrix

By iterating through a for loop in pandas, I created matrices with the same information for both the rows and columns.

Here is my current code:

```
for i in range(60):

eachMatrix = pd.DataFrame(index=df.WordTeams[i],columns=df.WordTeams[i])
eachMatrixcols = eachMatrix.columns.values
eachMatrixIndex = eachMatrix.index.values
for values in eachMatrixcols:
    for words in eachMatrixIndex:
        if values == words:
            eachMatrix.loc[words, values] = 0
        else:
            urlVector = requests.get( "XXXX?resp=" + values + "&modResp=" + words)
            loaded = json.loads(urlVector.text)
            print(loaded)
```

They look like this for example:

```
     dog cat med sox
 dog 0   NAN NAN NAN
 cat NAN 0   NAN NAN
 med NAN NAN 0   NAN
 sox NAN NAN NAN 0
```

The numbers denote the semantic distance between the words. To fill the NAN values, I am making a call to an API with the two words (dog and cat for example). The API works when I try it outside of my for loop or in the browser, but for some reason returns this error when called in my loop

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Traceback error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-0c4507581e84> in <module>()
 14             else:
 15                 urlVector = requests.get( "http://52.7.88.187/DSCoVAR-NLP/w2vScore.php?resp=" + values + "&modResp=" + words)
 16                 loaded = json.loads(urlVector.text)
 17                 print(loaded)
 18
```

I tried try/except clauses and it would only return a number for the first api call and then execute the except. Anyone know why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Turns out that there were white spaces in my words/values. Silly mistake but shows the importance of print statements.